# How to load a txt file in a NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can I load the content of a txt file divided by lines in a NSArray?
Basically, I have a file "count.txt" where I write the number of elements (and it works), "1t.txt" which represents the title of the first line and "1.txt" which represents the content.
I mean just the adding of values value by value.
Then when a user hits the title of the Table View I want he reads the content of "*.txt" (obviously easy if I have the index of array file)

For now I use this code:

```
- (void) loadMainArray
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
    {
    NSString *currentNumber;
    currentNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%it", i];
    NSLog(@"%i° file read", i);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:currentNumber ofType:@"txt"];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataFilePath])
    {
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:dataFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSArray *parsed = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
        mainArray = (__bridge NSMutableArray*)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFPropertyListRef)parsed, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
        NSLog(@"%@", parsed);

    }
    else{
    }
    }
}
```

(sorry if the code is not aligned as well but I'm not able so much in stackoverflow)
Anyway, after calling this method in the ViewLoad I get Signal SIGABRT, where I'm wrong?

N.B: max is set as well, I checked in NSLog. mainArray is an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Don't you want, by accident, `[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]`?

Comment: It gives me 2 warnings:  Incompatible pointers initializing...
stringWithContentsOfFile is deprecated..

Comment: @userXXX then you 1. look up the non-deprecated version of this method in the docs, 2. declare your array variable as an array instead of something else.

Comment: I wrote

NSArray *content = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:dataFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
            //NSArray *parsed = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

            mainArray = (__bridge NSMutableArray*)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFPropertyListRef)content, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers);
            NSLog(@"%@", content);

but it gives signal SIGABRT yet.

Comment: @userXXX Now you **look up the documentation of the methods I suggested,** in particular that of `componentsSeparatedByString:`. It already returns an `NSArray`, you don't need to write the other clutter you currently have.

Comment: This code was just for a little example, in fact the mainArray is assigned in the cycle (just for a simple test also because for now the list is of 1 element). Anyway your comments are *not* helpful to solve my question since everything I do what you said of it gives all the time the same error.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is

```
-(NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator;
```

which will divide the string at the specified separator. So basically you do this:

```
NSArray *parsed = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
//assuming you want a newLine as a separator
```

Now you go on and do your thing.
Have fun

EDIT:

im not sure your bridge to the mutable array is correct here.
It seems that you should use a NSData-Object to catch the return Value of your call to

```
CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy
```

You can always convert that to a MutableArray later, if there is any need.
This also explains your SIGABRT-error.

Comment: +1 **this** is what OP wants, he just doesn't realize it.

Comment: man I'm feeling like an idiot but it continues to give SIGABRT error, where am I wrong?

Comment: Make sure the file doesn't have any extra blank lines at the bottom. That always screws my up! Also, open it in **TextEdit** to make sure it is formatted the way you expect it to be.

Comment: please edit your question and post all relevant code.

Comment: It is formatted as txt and it doesn't have any blank at the bottom but still doesn't work!

Comment: that newLine at the bottom would just add an extra element. It would not cause a sigabrt. update your code, please.

Comment: maybe i found the issue. see edited answer...